# Writing a Python mail server with authentication

Tags: python, clojure, smtp, imap, pop3

I'm trying to write a simple mail server using Python.

I found smtpd that can be used as a simple smtp server, but I don't think it supports any form of authentication.

For pop or imap, I haven't found anything at all yet.

I do know Twisted has some support for both smtp and pop or imap, but I can't find any examples or tutorials about it.

An alternative would be to use Clojure, but I still have the same question:

Which libraries should I use and is there any documentation about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [example from Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/mail/examples/index.html#auto0).

And the [main page](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedMail).  Follow the link for documentation to find the example and a tutorial.

Edit:

Check the attachment for [this ticket](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3412) for an example IMAP server.  Definitely read the thread as it talks about the shortcomings of the example.

Comment: I saw this one. Only a SMTP server without any comments or explanation, and no IMAP server. This is going to be tough for sure...

Answer (score 1):

A bit late probably but for experimentation you might also want to check [pymta](http://www.schwarz.eu/opensource/projects/pymta) which is a pure-python SMTP implementation I'm using for some experiments/testing. It supports SMTP basic auth. Documentation should be at a 'decent' level, check the examples directory and the unit tests-

For anything production-related I'd go for twisted if you don't mind the asynchronous nature.